# React not rendering props but can see in console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

in my render, I have this `const arr = []`

In my return I have this

```
{
    this.state.rows.map((qc) =>
        qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
            qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) =>
              {!arr.includes(qc3.Defect) && arr.push(qc3.Defect) &&
                (<div className="row table">
                    <div className="column-label bold">{qc3.Defect}</div>
                    {console.log("testing", qc3.Defect)}
                </div>)
              }
            ) 
        )
    )
}
```

In my console.log I can actually see the 4 results, which is my desired outcome. It looks like this:

```
testing Scuff
testing Sunburn
testing Bruise
testing Hail damage
```

Any ideas on why nothing is rendering on the page?

Comment: remove `{}` in line 5 (code): `(!arr.includes(qc3.Defect) && arr.push(qc3.Defect) &&
                (<div className="row table">
                    <div className="column-label bold">{qc3.Defect}</div>
                    {console.log("testing", qc3.Defect)}
                </div>)
              )` or use `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have curly braces `{}`, you need to either change them to parentheses `()` or use an explicit `return` statement:

```
qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) =>
    {!arr.includes(qc3.Defect) && arr.push(qc3.Defect) &&
        (<div className="row table">
            <div className="column-label bold">{qc3.Defect}</div>
            {console.log("testing", qc3.Defect)}
        </div>)
      )
    )
```